# AWS API Gateway to internal Web Service (an API that's not publicly available)

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I've set up an Amazon API Gateway instance with a mock back-end and have it working perfectly.

I've also set up a RESTful API and deployed to AMAZON EC2. I can access it publically with Postman.

***What I would like to do now is proxy all calls through the API gateway. Then block public access to the EC2 instance.***

The problem is that I'm really struggling to find clear documentation on how this is done - which makes me think I might be doing things incorrectly, architecturally speaking.

My EC2 instance gives me a public DNS address, and a private one. I've tried setting the API gateway to point to the private address over HTTP, but the URL doesn't validate in the AWS Gateway - and wont save.

If someone could explain to me in plain English how this is *supposed* to work at a high level, and perhaps point to documentation, that would be absolute gold.

Comment: Do you think this can be a matter of incoming ports settings in EC2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what API Gateway calls a *private integration*.

API Gateway is not, itself, inside your VPC, so the solution uses a Network Load Balancer and [VPC PrivateLink](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/endpoint-service.html) to allow API Gateway to access your private resources.

Documentation and setup can be found here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html

Don't confuse private integrations with [private endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html) which allow the opposite -- with private endpoints, resources in your VPC are able to access an API deployed in API Gateway, without exposing the API Gateway endpoint itself to the Internet.